# Strong Password Suggestion Blocking User Input

Tags: ios

I am having problems with the strong password suggestion on iOS 14. When I navigate to my app's registration screen and tap the password field the strong password suggestion appears but the buttons to use the strong password, or select my own don't appear, and all touch input is blocked. I assume it's something with how my view controller is setup but can't figure out what it is. Any suggestions?

[image: Example]